# Equivalent 7za command for tar --force-local, -M, --file

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin, tar, 7za

Whats the correct replacement for the following cygwin command?

`tar cvf FRT_RTAC_OtherLogs.tar --force-local FRT_*.log`

I'm trying to replace it with:

`7za a FRT_RTAC_OtherLogs.tar FRT_*.log`

I'm trying to replace cygwin commands in a batch file with windows native commands. I`m completely new to these commands and searched a lot about these commands but couldn't find any proper replacement. I also need to replace the following commands too.

`tar zcv --force-local --file=%DUMPFILE%.gz %CAPDIR%`

`tar cvf %DUMPFILE% --force-local -M %DUMPFILE%.gz *LogBook_* *RTAC_OtherLogs*`

What does -M --file commands do and what are their equivalent 7zip commands?``

Comment: Does `man tar` work for you? If not look on the web for the man page or go to the manual for GNU tar here: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/

Comment: Is it windows native? @mvw

Comment: No `tar` is a Unix storage format and tool. Albeit 7-Zip for Windows can read it.

Comment: I need to know the equivalent 7-Zip commands for these tar commands @mvw